# Parsing JSON Postgres Parameter Function

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a function that receives a JSON parameter like this **funtion(p1 integer, p2 json)**

An external system (web application) is calling my function this way

```
{\"field\" ...}
```

and this error is returning

```
ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json Detail: Token "\" is invalid.
```

How i can read this json correctly ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix the web app.  If it is getting this wrong, who knows how many other ways it is also mangling the JSON?

If you want to play "malformating whack-a-mole", you could use REPLACE or TRANSLATE to remove the backslashes and then cast to json.  You can change the function signature to take text, then do the removal and cast inside the function itself.  Or you can do the removal inside the call to the function.

```
select function(p1,translate(p2,'\','')::json) from ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is self explainatory. {} is not valide json. "{}" is. Any valid should be a string. In javascript:

```
s = {}
d = "{}"
```

`JSON.parse(s)` will give:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at :1:6

While `JSON.parse(d)`  will pass. If you are using javascript, try using `JSON.stringify()` before passing your values to postgresql. (Or the equivalent in whatever language you use)